# How to remove loader icon form embed youtube video

Tags: javascript, youtube, embed

I am using [tublar](http://www.seanmccambridge.com/tubular/) jquery plugin in my project to embed youtube video. but i want to remove loader icon from the embedded youtube video. Please help.
 [Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QAU4.png)

Answer (score -1):

The loading icon is generated by the YouTube player and not the plugin. Tubular is just a wrapper for the YouTube iframe API.

An option to "hide" the icon is to hide the complete player while the video is loading. You can attach a callback to `window.onPlayerStateChange` to check if the player is really playing the video.

CSS:

```
#tubular-container {
  display: none;
}
```

Javascript/jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $('#wrapper').tubular({
    videoId: 'ab0TSkLe-E0',
    start: 3
  });

  window.onPlayerStateChange = function(state) {
    if (YT.PlayerState.PLAYING == 1) {
      $('#tubular-container').show();
    }
  };
});
```

Here is an example on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/jeyatohiji/edit?html,css,js,output)